# What development notepad should I use?

Tags: php, macos, notepad

I need recommendations  for a good (free) development notepad to work in on my new macbook, mainly for PHP, AJAX etc.

Comment: Do you mean a text editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/) is a free Mac text editor, which has PHP support built-in.

Comment: This looks great, quicker and easier considering my available time, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've request it be free - but really, I can't stress TextMate enough.  It's fantastic and it's also cheap (around $30).  It is well worth the price tag.

If you insist on staying free - try Eclipse with PDT.

Comment: Yes, its not free, but Textmate kicks butt. Well worth the investment!

Comment: Will take a look when i have some capital :p

Answer (score 2):

if you are familiar with vim, or got the time to learn a fairly complex text editor i would recommend checking out  [macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)

Answer (score 2):

[Vim](http://vim.org) is great text editor for writing web code. It has a steep learning curve, but works on almost all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also suggest trying out [Smultron](http://tuppis.com/smultron/). It's pretty lightweight, but it's a very nice (and free) editor. And, of course, it has support for PHP, JavaScript, and all the major web programming languages built in.

Comment: I use Smultron for all of my web coding and it works great for me. I'm a big fan of its regular expression search/replace and its hot-keys for inserting text snippets. I'm pretty sure the other editors do this as well (I haven't used them,) but Smultron is easy to use and has a great price.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs if you like customization to the ends of the universe.

Comment: Had trouble finding np++ for Mac, or maybe I just didn't look far enough :/

Comment: I wasn't aware that Notepad++ wasn't available for the Mac. Sorry, edited out.

Comment: No problem, I found out the hard way!

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) and [Carbon Emacs](http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html) for an Emacs-flavoured Mac editing experience. Carbon Emacs is closer to the Unix Emacs experience whereas the Aquamacs people have put considerable effort into OS X integration.

Answer (score 0):

Geany (geany.org) is my IDE of choice. It's lightweight, open-source, and I use it both for programming and note-taking. It supports PHP, C, Python, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/).
It has PHP and main AJAX libs support.

Comment: I will take a look, no harm in having more than one to mess with.

Comment: I use it with all my projects. In my opinion it's the best free web development tool (probably better than most of the paid too).

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest Komodo Studio